# How can I browse a site with broken encryption (SSL/TLS), when I'm not concerned with security?

Tags: firefox, security, browser, ssl, certificate

It often happens that I just want to browse some website, but the site has broken encryption (like an invalid certificate, an expired certificate, a CA 
that is down and so on) and the browser refuses to display the page.
This is much appreciated when dealing with things like online banking, but if I have no intention of doing anything privacy-sensitive (like signing in or sending personal information), I just find this as a hindrance.

Just replacing `https://...` with `http://...` would allow you to establish a plain old unencrypted connection in the past, but nowadays most sites automatically redirect you to a secured connection. Some of these errors can be circumvented by forcing the browser to accept a certificate exception, but this is unwieldy and can become a security risk if I forget to remove the dubious cert afterwards.

---

Is there a way to force a browser to only accept plaintext connections, only for a single misbehaving domain, and preferably for just a single session? I personally use Firefox, but details about other browsers are welcome too.

Comment: "but nowadays most sites automatically redirect you to a secured connection."  You have no control over that -- if their webserver redirects HTTP requests to HTTPS, then you're SOL.

Comment: Most browsers other then Firefox allow you to connect to an unsafe site without adding an exception.

Comment: What makes you so sure you're talking to the real site, and not an imposter that copied their HTML and DNS-hijacked you?

Comment: Is this for a trusted, internal server?

Comment: @Spiff Nothing at all, but *I'm not interested in security* if I just want to e.g. download some random research paper or read a neglected blog from a few years ago. I just don't care if it's an impostor, as I'm not going to buy stuff from such a site or post personal information. Incognito mode is of course preferable when doing this.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure your security model included impostors (say, malware sites that infect your computer via your browser), not just people snooping on your traffic to a "real, but misconfigured" site.

Comment: @Spiff That's a valid concern, but I am willing to take the risk. Perhaps I should mention that in the question.

Comment: Looks like an easy way to add a temporary exception is what you need. There's a deprecated Firefox addon called Skip Cert Error that does what it says. Nothing current and recent though...

Comment: Ideally you should not access websites facing security issue in the browsers. As you know about the "Add exception" option to access those sites but you must not check "Permanently store this exception" for future consideration. Otherwise browsers will bypass security warning for particular sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really any way to request only non-encrypted connections if the server itself is forcing a redirect.  However, you should be able to 'Permanently store' and exception as follows:

1. Click '**Advanced**' on the 'Your connection is not secure' page
   [image]
2. Next, click the '**Add Exception...**' button
   [image]
3. Ensure that the box for 'Permanently store this exception' is selected, and then click '**Confirm Security Exception**'
   [image]